# Can I make last part of counting sort become to be starting from lowest index?

Tags: sorting, counting

Counting sort is originally like below code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) c[i] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) c[a[i]]++;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) c[i] = c[i] + c[i - 1];
for (int i = 8; i >= 1; i--) {
    b[c[a[i]]] = a[i];
    c[a[i]]--;
}
```

In the above, last for loop iterates from last index because of stability of counting sort.

But, I want to iterate from first index 1 as well as maintaining the stability of sorting.

I'm trying and thinking lots of time, I cannot do. How can I do?

Comment: Obviously, your question is valid without any motivation. But, still, why? You have a version of counting sort that works for you, but you want to make an arbitrary-looking change that breaks it, while somehow not breaking it. What's wrong with the original version?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I just curious about reverse order, just that.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the last loop, `c[i]` holds the index of last element of bucket `i` plus 1. It's why when you use `c[i]` to address items in bucket `i` you need to go back. But `c[i-1]` contains index of the first element of bucket `i`, so you can just use it... except that you need index for bucket 0 too.

So the simplest way is to modify third cycle making it to write **initial** index of bucket i to `c[i]`. It may be done f.e. with extra temporary (note that `i` in revised loop starts from 0):

```
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) 
{
    sum += c[i];  
    c[i] = sum - c[i];
}
```

Note that since indexes in `b` starts from 1, you need to pre-increment `c[a[i]]` in new version of last loop (if indexes in `b` should go from 0, do post-increment instead):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    c[a[i]]++;
    b[c[a[i]]] = a[i];
}
```